# Closure and value lifetimes

Tags: rust, closures

I'm only learning Rust and I'm stumbling upon some stuff, as all, I suppose.
And this one I cannot find an answer on my own and I've tried.

What I'm doing is playing around message stream abstraction and it's going fine unless I'd know how to write this test:

```rust
        #[test]
        fn take_1() {
            let mut delivery_count = 1;
            let delivery_listener = |item: &i32| {
                delivery_count += 1;
            };
            let stream = super::Stream::<i32>::new(Some(Box::new(delivery_listener)));
            // [Push 10 messages to the stream here]
            assert_eq!(delivery_count, 10);
        }
```

Here I'm implementing a kind of ack mechanism - I push messages to Stream object and list for delivery confirm through closure and that obviously isn't really working and fails with following err:

```
`delivery_count` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough
```

I did try same approach with `Vec<i32>` and even with `Rc<RefCell<i32>>` and miserably failed each time as there was no way I'd manage to attach a lifetime to that variable.
I'm quite sure this is something simple I'm missing - I need community help! ;)

EDIT:
Here's a reproducible example:

```rust
struct QuasiStream<T> {
    delivery_listener: Option<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn FnMut(&T)>>>>,
}
impl <T> QuasiStream<T> {
    pub fn new(delivery_listener: Option<Box<dyn FnMut(&T)>>) -> Self {
        QuasiStream {
            delivery_listener: match delivery_listener {
                Some(delivery_listener) => Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(delivery_listener))),
                None => None,
            },
        }
    }
    pub fn publish(&self, item: T) {
        if let Some(delivery_listener) = &self.delivery_listener {
            delivery_listener.as_ref().borrow_mut()(&item);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn take_1() {
    let mut delivery_count = 0;
    let delivery_listener = |item: &i32| {
        delivery_count += 1;
    };

    let stream = QuasiStream::<i32>::new(Some(Box::new(delivery_listener)));
    for i in 0..10 {
        stream.publish(i);
    }
    // [Push messages to the stream here]
    assert_eq!(delivery_count, 10);
}
```

Comment: Can you please try providing a minimal reproducible example, if possible

Comment: Sure! Just updated post with example.

Comment: `Rc<RefCell<Box<...>>>` is really quite a turducken.

Comment: You may want to switch to something like `Arc<RwLock<i32>>` as your counter, then you can manipulate it from within that block as an owned handle.

Comment: Yo dawg I heard you like smart pointers so I put smart pointers into your smart pointers so that you can point smartly when pointing. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dyn Trait` is interpreted as `dyn Trait + 'static`, which is why the compiler wants that the borrowed reference lives forever.

Add explicit lifetime parameters to fix that.

Then, you still get a borrow checker complaint because `delivery_count` is borrowed mutably for `stream` and then you want to print it. So for demonstration purposes, we put the stream stuff into its own block so the stream gets dropped and the borrow gets released.

See here:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c7df989bff3d46ba8113255f0f1fe7b

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
struct QuasiStream<'a, T> {
    delivery_listener: Option<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>>>>,
}
impl<'a, T> QuasiStream<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(delivery_listener: Option<Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>>) -> Self {
        QuasiStream {
            delivery_listener: match delivery_listener {
                Some(delivery_listener) => Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(delivery_listener))),
                None => None,
            },
        }
    }
    pub fn publish(&self, item: T) {
        if let Some(delivery_listener) = &self.delivery_listener {
            delivery_listener.as_ref().borrow_mut()(&item);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn take_1() {
    let mut delivery_count = 0;
    let delivery_listener = |item: &i32| {
        delivery_count += 1;
    };

    {
        let stream = QuasiStream::<i32>::new(Some(Box::new(delivery_listener)));
        for i in 0..10 {
            stream.publish(i);
        }
    }

    // [Push messages to the stream here]
    assert_eq!(delivery_count, 10);
}
```

Comment: PS: If you start at 1 and increment 10 times, your count should be 11, not 10. So I start the count at 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your type `Stream` holds a `Box<dyn FnMut(T)>`. Normally, boxing a `FnMut` (or any trait) requires the closure to live for `'static`. You can relax this by adding a lifetime parameter (using a type alias because I'm going to reuse it):

```rs
type Handler<'a, T> = Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>;

pub struct Stream<'a, T> {
    handler: Option<Handler<'a, T>>,
}
```

Then, in your test function, it should work nearly unchanged, but it doesn't:

```rs
fn take_1() {
    let mut delivery_count = 0;
    let delivery_listener = |_item: &i32| {
        delivery_count += 1;
    };
    let mut stream = super::Stream::new(Some(Box::new(delivery_listener)));
    stream.process(5);
    stream.process(5);
    stream.process(5);
    
    assert_eq!(delivery_count, 3);
}
```

Normally, [non-lexical lifetimes](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html) will handle this, ensuring `stream`—and therefore the borrow inside the closure of `delivery_count`—is dropped before the assert. But it doesn't, for whatever reason (either a limitation of the borrow checker or to defend against some scenario that I'm missing), so you need to make a block:

```rs
let mut delivery_count = 0;
{
    let delivery_listener = |_item: &i32| {
        delivery_count += 1;
    };
    let mut stream = super::Stream::new(Some(Box::new(delivery_listener)));
    stream.process(5);
    stream.process(5);
    stream.process(5);
}
assert_eq!(delivery_count, 3);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=939b7afce6ad3fcf87f2a1cb5b1af2a9)

Comment: You've been super helpful! Thank you! I love our programmers community ;)